# Neural Net XOR Genetic Algorithms

Tags: c++, ai, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

New to Neural Networks and before I move on to gradient descent I would like to make sure I have got basic idea right. (Sorry that the class is called perceptron I know that this isnt technically right, I adapted this code from 
and AND gate NN). This NN is made to learn the XOR function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <valarray>
#define POPSIZE 100
using namespace std;
float randfloat();
float Sigmoid(float A);
class Perceptron{
public:
    Perceptron()
    {
        weights[0] = randfloat();
        weights[1] = randfloat();
        weights[2] = randfloat();
        weights[3] = randfloat();
        weights[4] = randfloat();
        weights[5] = randfloat();
        weights[6] = randfloat();
        weights[7] = randfloat();
        weights[8] = randfloat();
        CalculateError();
    }
    float FeedForward(int A, int B)
    {
        float Sum1 = A*weights[0] + B*weights[1] + bias*weights[4];
        float Sum2 = A*weights[2] + B*weights[3] + bias*weights[5];
        float Sum3 = Sigmoid(Sum1)*weights[6]
                    + Sigmoid(Sum2)*weights[7]
                    + bias*weights[8];
        return Sigmoid(Sum3);

    }
    void PrintStats()
    {
        cout << "weights =" << weights[0] << " " << weights[1] << " " << weights[2];
        cout << "\nerror= " << normalisedError;
    }
    void CalculateError()
    {
        error = abs(0-FeedForward(1,1)) +
        abs(1-FeedForward(1,0)) +
        abs(1-FeedForward(0,1)) +
        abs(0-FeedForward(0,0));
        normalisedError = error*10;
    }
    float GetNormalisedError()
    {
        return normalisedError;
    }
    void SetFitnessScore(int i)
    {
    fitnessScore = i;
    }
    int GetFitnessScore()
    {
        return fitnessScore;
    }
friend void CrossOver(Perceptron A, Perceptron B, Perceptron &C);
friend void TransferGenes(Perceptron A, Perceptron &B);
friend int ChooseFittestSpecies(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE]);
private:
    float weights[9];
    int bias = 1;
    float error =0;
    int normalisedError;
    int fitnessScore;
};

int ChooseParent(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE]);
int ChooseFittestSpecies(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE]);
int ChooseWorstSpecies(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE]);
void Reproduce(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE], Perceptron C[POPSIZE]);



int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Perceptron pop[POPSIZE];

    Perceptron Children[POPSIZE];

for(int x =0 ;  x < 100 ; x++){
    Reproduce(pop, Children);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < POPSIZE ; i ++)
    {
        TransferGenes(Children[i], pop[i]);
        pop[i].CalculateError();
    }
}

int alphaSpecies = ChooseFittestSpecies(pop);

cout << "Most fit species is: " << alphaSpecies << endl;
    cout << "inputs:" << endl;
    cout << "1 1 : " << pop[alphaSpecies].FeedForward(1,1) << endl;
    cout << "0 1 : " << pop[alphaSpecies].FeedForward(0,1) << endl;
    cout << "1 0 : " << pop[alphaSpecies].FeedForward(1,0) << endl;
    cout << "0 0 : " << pop[alphaSpecies].FeedForward(0,0) << endl;

    return 0;
}

void TransferGenes(Perceptron A, Perceptron &B)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
        B.weights[i] = A.weights[i];
    }
}

void Reproduce(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE], Perceptron C[POPSIZE])
{
    int ParentA, ParentB;
    for(int i = 0; i < POPSIZE ;  i++)
    {
        ParentA = ChooseParent(pop);
        ParentB = ChooseParent(pop);
        CrossOver(pop[ParentA], pop[ParentB], C[i]);
    }
}

void CrossOver(Perceptron A, Perceptron B, Perceptron &C)
{
    int random;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i ++)
    {
        random = rand()%2;
        if(random)
        {
            C.weights[i] = A.weights[i];
        }else{
            C.weights[i] = B.weights[i];
        }
    }
}

int ChooseParent(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE])
{
    int GreatestError = pop[0].GetNormalisedError();
    for(int i = 1; i < POPSIZE ; i++)
    {
        if(pop[i].GetNormalisedError() > GreatestError)
        {
            GreatestError = pop[i].GetNormalisedError();
        }
    }

    int totalFitness=0;

    for(int i =0 ; i  < POPSIZE ;  i++)
    {
        pop[i].SetFitnessScore(GreatestError  + 1 - pop[i].GetNormalisedError());
        totalFitness = totalFitness + pop[i].GetFitnessScore();
    }

    int random = rand()%totalFitness +1;

    int ParentSelector = 0;
    int ParentIndex;
    for(int i=0;ParentSelector<random;i++)
    {
        ParentSelector = ParentSelector + pop[i].GetFitnessScore();
        ParentIndex = i;
    }

    return ParentIndex;
}

float randfloat()
{
    float f = static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/10));
    int Pos_or_Neg = rand()%2;
    if(Pos_or_Neg)
    {
        return f;
    }else{
    return -f;
    }
}
float Sigmoid(float A)
{
    return 1/(1+exp(-2*A));
}
int ChooseFittestSpecies(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE])
{
    int MostFitParent = 0;

    for(int i = 0;  i  < POPSIZE ;  i++)
    {
        if(pop[i].error < pop[MostFitParent].error)
        {
            MostFitParent = i;
        }
    }
    return MostFitParent;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot that I could say, but I'm going to limit to what I consider the most major issues:

**Questionable Coding Practices**

The big two are [`using namespace std` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2069064) and [`rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).  The former is straightforward: just drop it and prefix all the `std` references with `std::`. It's only five characters and adds a great deal to readability. There's really no reason to avoid it.

For the latter, `rand()` just is not the best way to generate random numbers. Additionally, it is very unclear to me what is actually going in in `randfloat()`. It'd be much better to use the C++11 `<random>` library for this, specifically [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution):

```
float randfloat() {
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    static std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(YOUR_MIN, YOUR_MAX);
    return dis(gen);
}
```

I cannot tell what your actual min and max are - so fill those spaces in accordingly. Once you get over the `mt19937` boilerplate, this is a much more straightforward way to do this.

Additionally, avoid macros:

```
#define POPSIZE 100
```

should be:

```
static constexpr int POPSIZE = 100;
```

And please **use consistent indentation**!

**Weights**

First, you could generate them all using [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate%60) instead of repeating the same line of code:

```
std::generate(std::begin(weights), std::end(weights), randfloat);
```

Secondly, prefer [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to a raw array. This will let you do:

```
void TransferGenes(Perceptron A, Perceptron &B)
{
    B.weights = A.weights;
}
```

No loop necessary. Although here, the first argument should definitely be a reference to const to avoid the copy. And `A` and `B` are rather unhelpful names, prefer something like:

```
void TransferGenes(Perceptron const& src, Perceptron& dst)
{
    dst.weights = src.weights;
}
```

Typically the `dst` argument goes first (e.g. `memcpy`), but YMMV.

You may also want to strongly consider using `double` instead of `float`.

**Passing Arrays**

Writing something like:

```
int ChooseFittestSpecies(Perceptron pop[POPSIZE]);
```

is meaningless since the `POPSIZE` value doesn't matter. This is a function that takes a `Perceptron*` as an argument. So you don't actually know what the size of the array is, despite the code giving the appearance that you do. Here, I would encourage you strongly to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
int ChooseFittestSpecies(std::vector<Perceptron>& pop);
```

Vectors are *much* easier to deal with. Plus, if somebody passes you a vector whose size is different from `POPSIZE`, your code will do the right thing still.

Furthermore, this particular function could take advantage of [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), which clarifies the intent better:

```
int ChooseFittestSpecies(const std::vector<Perceptron>& pop)
{
    auto it = std::min_element(pop.begin(), pop.end(), 
                               [](const Perceptron& lhs, const Perceptron& rhs){
                                   return lhs.error < rhs.error;
                               });
    return std::distance(pop.begin(), it);
}
```